# Numpy.putmask with images

Tags: python, arrays, image, image-processing, numpy

I have an image converted to a ndarray with RGBA values. Suppose it's 50 x 50 x 4.

I want to replace all the pixels with values `array([255, 255, 255, 255])` for `array([0, 0, 0, 0])`. So:

```
from numpy import *
from PIL import Image
def test(mask):
        mask = array(mask)
        find = array([255, 255, 255, 255])
        replace = array([0, 0, 0, 0])
        return putmask(mask, mask != find, replace)

mask = Image.open('test.png')
test(mask)
```

What am I doing wrong? That gives me a `ValueError: putmask: mask and data must be the same size`. Yet if I change the arrays to numbers (find = 255, replace = 0) it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this kind of channel masking is to split the array into r,g,b,a channels, then define the index using numpy logical bit operations:

```
import numpy as np
import Image

def blackout(img):
    arr = np.array(img)
    r,g,b,a=arr.T
    idx = ((r==255) & (g==255) & (b==255) & (a==255)).T
    arr[idx]=0
    return arr

img = Image.open('test.png')
mask=blackout(img)
img2=Image.fromarray(mask,mode='RGBA')
img2.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

A more concise way to do this is

```
img = Image.open('test.png')
a = numpy.array(img)
a[(a == 255).all(axis=-1)] = 0
img2 = Image.fromarray(a, mode='RGBA')
```

More generally, if the items of `find` and `repl` are not all the same, you can also do

```
find = [1, 2, 3, 4]
repl = [5, 6, 7, 8]
a[(a == find).all(axis=-1)] = repl
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses `putmask` and I think is the closest to the OPs code.  There are two errors in the original code that the OP should know about:  1) putmask is an in-place operation.  It returns `None`.  2) `putmask` also requires equal-sized arrays.  It (too bad) doesn't have an `axis` keyword argument.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img1 = Image.open('test.png')
arry = np.array(img1)
find = np.array([255, 255, 255, 255])
repl = np.array([  0,   0,   0,   0])
# this is the closest to the OPs code I could come up with that
# compares each pixel array with the 'find' array
mask = np.all(arry==find, axis=2)
# I iterate here just in case repl is not always the same value
for i,rep in enumerate(repl):
    # putmask works in-place - returns None
    np.putmask(arry[:,:,i], mask, rep)

img2 = Image.fromarray(arry, mode='RGBA')
img2.save('testx.png')
```

Comment: 1. Why do you use `np.logical_not(imga-find)` instead of `imga != find`? 2. What is `imga` anyway? 3. How would you avoid the loop in the case that all entries in `repl` are the same?

Comment: @ Sven Marnach:  2) Thanks `imga` should have been `arry`.  1) I wasn't aware you could broadcast with `==`.  3) I'd create a 3D mask and `putmask(arry, mask, 0)`.