# What is the difference between a PIL Image from PIL.Image.open and a NumPy Image matplotlib.image.imread ?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I would like to know why I should or shouldn't use a matplotlib image over a PIL image. I know that matplotlib uses PIL to load any image that is not a PNG, but what is the advantage in having it in a numpy array over the PIL backend representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PIL API includes function for performing a [wide range of image manipulations](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imageops.htm). But of course, it does not provide a function for all conceivable operations. Numpy is useful when you have a mathematical operation to perform on the image which is not built into the PIL API. PIL has a [way of altering pixels](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm#putpixel) one-by-one but because if its reliance on Python loops it can be a very slow way to manipulate a large image (or many images).

Numpy math is relatively fast and it has an expressive syntax which 
can make coding new image manipulations easier. Moreover, scipy has many additional [image manipulating functions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html) which can be applied to numpy arrays.

Here are a few examples:

- [emboss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2034258/190597)
- [converting rgb to hsv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7274986/190597)
- [replacing a color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5536415/190597)